# Where with IN operator using Linq on NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, queryover

I have a linq query with NHibernate using `Session.Query<T>` method and I in this query I Fetch some complex properties and collection properties. I would like to know, how can I add an condition with `IN` operator from an `int[]`? Look my code:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int[] idCategories) 
{
    // how to add IN condition here or a subquery 
    var query = Session.Query<Product>()
                   .Where(?????)
                   .Fetch(x=>x.Category)
                   .FetchMany(x=>x.Status).ThenFetch(x=>x.Item);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I have another method doing a query to get this `int[]` and I would like to apply it here, or if is there any way to add this subquery on the `IN` operator, I really appreciate!

OBS: I could convert `int[]` to `List<int>` if its necessary.

### Edits

I got this `int[]` by a query like:

```
return session.Query<Category>.Where(...).Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```

My second question is, how could I add this query as a subquery to filter by category?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need the `IN` operator. You can just do it like this:

```
.Where(x => idCategories.Contains(x.Category))
```

Note: `Contains` is an extension method. You need to ensure that you have a using statement for `System.Linq`, but you probably already have it.

Comment: I will try this. I have just one more question. How could i do a subquery that return this int[] and apply on the Constains method? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your second question. Why do you need to do a subquery to get the `int[]`? Isn't that what you pass in as `idCategories`?

Comment: I add some edits on the main question. Take a look. If you coudl help me I really appretiate man! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid we've reached the boundary of my NHibernate knowledge. I would suggest posting the as-yet-unanswered second part of this question as its own question if you still need it.

Comment: Thank you man, you have help me with this awser. I'll post another question later with more detail about it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on Restrictions, for example

```
var query = Session.Query<Product>()
     .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property<Product>x=>x.Id),idCategories))
     .Fetch(x=>x.Category)
     .FetchMany(x=>x.Status).ThenFetch(x=>x.Item);
```

Comment: You can't mix `Session.Query<>()` with `NHibernate.Criterion.Subqueries`.  I think you were referring to `Session.QueryOver<>()`, which the original question was not about.

Answer (score 1):

About sub query, you need Subqueries class

```
var query = Session.Query<Product>()
               .Where(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Product>(x=>x.Id)...)
               .Fetch(x=>x.Category)
               .FetchMany(x=>x.Status).ThenFetch(x=>x.Item);
```

for more details please look here [How to do subqueries in nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969250/how-to-do-subqueries-in-nhibernate)

Comment: You can't mix `Session.Query<>()` with `NHibernate.Criterion.Subqueries`.  I think you were referring to `Session.QueryOver<>()`, which the original question was not about.