# How to use Any operator in NHibernate to select by two parameters?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a UserObject that contains `ID`, `GUID`, `Name` and `Age`.
My function gets a list of objects the contains only ID and GUID, and need to return the UserObject(s) the matches the params. For example:

```
userIds = new [] {
    { ID = 1, GUID = "AAAAAA" },
    { ID = 2, GUID = "AAAAAB" },
};

var result = from user in session.Query<UserObject>()
             where userIds.Any(u => u.ID == user.ID && u.GUID == user.GUID)
             select user;
```

The query will return the `UserObjects` only if the `ID` exists and the `GUID` matches. The problem is that NHibernate does not support the Any method. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How is the NHibernate entity Id of the `UserObject` class mapped?

Comment: The ID is an Id column and GUID is regular non-null column.

Comment: I thought any was now supported, what version of NH are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe NHiberante does not support the `Any` operator on an unmapped array (`userIds`).

You can try to use,

```
var result = session.Query<UserObject>()
                    .Where(user => userIds.Select(u => u.ID).Contains(user.ID))
                    .Where(user => userIds.Select(u => u.GUID).Contains(user.GUID))
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

As shown in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524399/1250033).

Answer (score 0):

How about looping over the passed in objects, adding disjuctions as you go along for each record.

```
var c = session.CreateCriteria<User>();
var disjunction = new Disjunction();
foreach (var ids in userIds)
{
    var q = new Conjunction().Add(Restrictions.Eq("userId", ids.userId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("GUID", ids.GUID));
    disjunction.Add(q); 
}
c.Add(disjunction);
```

Sorry if the code does not compile just as written and is not at all tested as I am away from VS right now. The code can also probably be written more concisely. What the code is effectively doing is generating a query of the type "Select * from Users where ((userId = userId1 and GUID = Guid1) or(userId = userId2 and GUID = GUID2) or....)"
Hope this is what you were looking for.